# How to remove default padding from ExpansionTile's header

Tags: flutter, dart

By default we have 16 horizontal paddings in *ExpansionTile's* header, because it is *ListTile* and it has

```
/// If null, `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)` is used.
    final EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding;
```

So we have spaces on left and right
[image]

**How to remove them?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The chosen answer is not working fully.
In order to get it right you should go :

```
ListTileTheme(
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
   dense: true,
   horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
   minLeadingWidth: 0,
   child: ExpansionTile(...)
)
```

Comment: Bruh, This won't work either.

Comment: horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
   minLeadingWidth: 0, are the key

Comment: This worked for me. The property minLeadingWidth will solve the issue. minLeadingWidth has a default value of 40.0. 

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/minLeadingWidth.html

Answer (score 42):

*ListTile* is styled with *ListTileTheme* and we can add own styles for child ListTile like this

```
ListTileTheme(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: ExpansionTile(...)
)
```

Comment: it only removes padding from left side only

Comment: it does not remove the vertical padding

Comment: Add ListTileTheme(minVerticalPadding: 0.0), property.

Answer (score 5):

ExpansionTile has tilePadding property, that you can set to

```
tilePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0)
```

Comment: Works for leading but still there is a space between leading and title with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

To customize the Expansion tile widget without much padding and spacing you can do the following changes

```
ListTileTheme(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        dense: true //removes additional space vertically
        child: ExpansionTile(...))
```

If the trailing space needs to be removed, you can use the modified Expansiontile widget as mentioned in   https://stackoverflow.com/a/64162389/12661107 .

Answer (score 1):

Seems its still not possible I still have padding above and below. heres my theme data. Note the vertical padding is intentional.

```
  child: ListTileTheme(
    data: ListTileThemeData(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
      minLeadingWidth: 0,
      dense: true,
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems it isn't possible with current Flutter version (1.20.3).

A feature was proposed but closed:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57577

So two options possible now:

- Copy ExpansionTile widget source code into your project and alter it as you wish.
- Or use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/configurable_expansion_tile

Comment: It is all right for Flutter 1.20.3+. Use latest stable to be sure. This [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57577) is about height & space, not about padding. Don't confuse people with wrong answers

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by adding horizontaGap -ve value

ListTileTheme(
dense: true,
horizontalTitleGap: -8.0,
minLeadingWidth: 0,
child: ExpansionTile(...)

You can adjust for your preferece gap

Answer (score 0):

Use an ExpansionTileTheme widget. It allows for proper customization for the expansion tile. It also removes the trailing widget, which I needed to do in my case.

```
ExpansionTileTheme(
                        data: const ExpansionTileThemeData(
                          iconColor: Colors.white,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            border: Border(
                              top: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFE6E6E6), width: 1),
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFE6E6E6), width: 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this configuration of `ListTileTheme`:

```
ListTileTheme(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          dense: true,
          horizontalTitleGap: 0,
          minLeadingWidth: 0,
          minVerticalPadding: 0, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [UnconstrainedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UnconstrainedBox-class.html) class

NOTE:- a warning will be given in debug mode and Implement it with your own logic

> Creates a widget that imposes no constraints on its child, allowing it to render at its "natural" size. If the child overflows the parents constraints, a warning will be given in debug mode

Implement it with your own logic to meet the requirement. Use transform if you want to

```
             //this code is only for reference implement you own logic
              ExpansionTile(
                title: UnconstrainedBox(child: Transform.translate( offset: Offset(30, 0),child:
                Container(color: Colors.lightGreen, width: 350,height:50, child: Text('A long title................................................... which overflows the padding')))),
                children: [
                  Text('Subtitle'),
                ],
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove padding from all sides

`tilePadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0,vertical: 0),`

Answer (score 0):

```
visualDensity: const VisualDensity(vertical: -4),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?